# Combining DataFrameTime object with ExportReports function in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, reports

using python in ArcGIS, I'm trying to combine the ExportReports function with the DataFrameTime object. For every date interval, an image of the Layoutview is exported and all the visible layers are supposed to be saved in the report.I am able to get the images to match the dates, however the report doesn't change and just adds all the files to the report including those not visible in the current time frame.

```
 pageCount = 1    
while df.time.currentTime <= endTime: 
    activeDF = df.time.currentTime
    timeLyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(lyr,"RSII1")
    extentPolygon = arcpy.Polygon(arcpy.Array([df.extent.lowerLeft,df.extent.lowerRight, df.extent.upperRight, df.extent.upperLeft]),df.spatialReference)

    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(lyr, "WITHIN", extentPolygon, "", "NEW_SELECTION")
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr, "SUBSET_SELECTION")
    arcpy.SelectLayerBYAttribute_management(lyr, "CLEAR_SELECTION")
    arcpy.Delete_management("RSII1")
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd, path + "\Test1.png") #Creates a single file of the current time frame picture to be added to report

     # Generates report
    arcpy.mapping.ExportReport(report_source=lyr,report_layout_file=path + r"\Report.rlf",output_file=path + r"\temp" + str(pageCount) + ".pdf",dataset_option="SELECTED",starting_page_number=pageCount)

     # Appends pages into final report    
    pdfDoc.appendPages(path + r"\temp" + str(pageCount) + ".pdf")
    os.remove(path + r"\temp" + str(pageCount) + ".pdf")
    pageCount = pageCount + 1

    df.time.currentTime = df.time.currentTime + interval
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe I know what is going on. While I have never used reports in ArcMap, looking at your code, it appears you're selecting features that are within the dataframe, then you select all select a subset of features in the same layer (there is no where clause) then you clear the selection.  All of this occurs before you export the PNG or the report.  Your report is set to run on selected data.  However, if you're clearing the selection first, then your report will not give you the correct results.

Comment: Hi Fezter, Thank you for your response. I tried it before without clearing the selection but I kept getting the same results of all the records being generated in the report. I'm begging to think that it may not be possible to generate the report based on the "selection by location" and may have to be done by "selection by attribute", if I want only the selected files to appear in the report. I'll try it based on attributes. Thank you again.